# MacBook Pro updated to EL Captain 10.11 but QuickTime Player didn't upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, quicktime, macos

The ONLY reason I upgraded to EL Captain because the new QuickTime Player allows me to make a video of my app while I play on my device. However, I've upgraded to EL Captain 10.11 but the QuickTime Player is still version 10.4

The El Capitan upgrade went smoothly for my MacBook Pro. Everything works well. How do I update the QuickTime Player? I tried going through App store but in search, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

QuickTime 10.4 is the newest version. It was already possible to record your iOS-device in Yosemite. [Source](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/record-iphone-screen-quicktime/).